# extracting a set of elements from xml schema

Tags: python, xml, xsd

how can I use Python code to extract the red part [of this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NXJX.png)?
More specifically, I need the "name" attribute of each xs:element, like PURPOSE_CD, TYPE_CD and so on
I tried using this code, but it doesn't work

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
for item in root.findall('NewDataSet'):
  print('found')
  item_text=item.findall("xs:element").text
  item_name=item.get('name')
  print(item_name)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: An XPath like `//xs:element[@name="OfferteOperatori"]/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element` should give you the set of elements in the red box.

Comment: Thank you  Jens, but I'm not sure to catch. I get "cannot use absolute path on element" if I use root.findall('//xs:element[@name="OfferteOperatori"]/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I couldn't explain well my answer to Jens (thanks!).
If I use:

```
for item in root.findall('//xs:element'):
```

, I get

```
SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element
```

If, instead, I write:

```
root = etree.XML(my_xml)
root.xpath('//xs:element[@name="OfferteOperatori"]/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element')
```

, then I get

```
XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Here is the answer:

```
columns=tuple([(elem.attrib['name'], elem.tag) for elem in root.getiterator() 
               if elem.tag=="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element" and elem.text==None])
```

Thanks